# css vertical button group - ignores justify-content

Tags: html, css, button

I wish to have a group of buttons spaced vertically in a container (following the css flex style space-around). Below is the complete html section that demonstrates the problem I am having - the buttons always build from the top of the container (as if flex-start) no matter what I've tried (the style "container" below just sets up an arbitrary, fixed size container into which I'd want the buttons - which are individually and together less height than the container - to stack vertically as noted.)

I am not certain of the purpose of display: block; within the class abutton (presence/absence appears to have no effect.)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
}
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.abutton {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class = "abutton">Button 1</button>
    <button class = "abutton">Button 2</button>
    <button class = "abutton">Button 3</button>
    <button class = "abutton">Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.buttons` add width: 100% and height: 100%; so that it fills the full container space:

```css
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Working example:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
}
.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}
.abutton {
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class = "abutton">Button 1</button>
    <button class = "abutton">Button 2</button>
    <button class = "abutton">Button 3</button>
    <button class = "abutton">Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, fixed!

Comment: @wb0gaz - I'm glad to see that Yuran's answer worked for you.  Please remember to give them credit by upvoting the answer and selecting it as the answer that solved your issue-- this provides reputation points to them, as well as providing feedback to anybody visiting this question that this answer was useful.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @wb0gaz  If you wish to center all the buttons in the box, add `align-items:center;` as far as the `display: block;` in the .abutton, it doesn't really matter so you can just remove it.